# devise hidden field for redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have devise redirecting to previous page setup for my application using hidden_field_tag.
Now I added the favorite action on my website and I'd like that user once click the favorite button can signup using a popover and that favorite get saved. 
I created the popover using a modal and it's working but once the user sign up - the favorite is obviously not created.
I tried to pass an hidden field just for the modal like this

```
<%= hidden_field_tag("page_id", "favorite") %>
```

then on application_controller I added

```
if params[:page_id] == "favorite"
  favorite_item_path(@item, type: "favorite", method: :put)
end
```

the items controller has the favorite action like this

```
def favorite
@item = Item.find(params[:id]) 

type = params[:type]
if type == "favorite"
  current_user.favorites << @item
  redirect_to :back

elsif type == "unfavorite"
  current_user.favorites.delete(@item)
  redirect_to :back

else
  redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
end
```

end

here is the form on the modal

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Create a username", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Enter your email", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Choose your password", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= hidden_field_tag("page_id", "favorite") %>
        <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn" %>
      </div>


    <% end %>
```

and when I try to signup i get the following error

No route matches {:action=>"favorite", :controller=>"items", :id=>nil, :method=>:put, :type=>"favorite"} missing required keys: [:id]

How can I pass the id on the modal?

thanks

Comment: Pls show the entire form, because the error seems to be related to the form you are submitting.

Comment: @Alfie right. Just added

Comment: Not sure why exactly you are getting the error, but i can tell you one thing, you are trying to submit the form `f` and since `hidden_field_tag` isn't part of the form, even if this form works, won't submit the value along with other form fields. you should still use `f.text_field`